# Is there a Sublime Text 2 color scheme based on Github's syntax highlighting?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext2, color-scheme

I found [this one for GVim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2855), but I want one for Sublime Text 2.

[image]

(This is a really hard thing to Google for, because so many ST2 color schemes are *hosted* on Github.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GitHub TextMate theme](https://github.com/sbecker/github_editor_theme) by sbecker (compatible with Sublime Text 2).

Answer (score 6):

[Dayle Rees' Colour Schemes](https://github.com/daylerees/colour-schemes) includes a Github-themed color scheme; the entire set of 41 schemes is available through [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control) under the non-British moniker "Dayle Rees Color Schemes".

[image: Dayle Rees' Github colour scheme]
The font in the screenshot is the excellent (and free!) [Adobe Source Code Pro](https://blogs.adobe.com/typblography/2012/09/source-code-pro.html) ([download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecodepro.adobe/)).